# HTML POST with incuded Jquery Forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have the following HTML:

```
 </td><td>
            <div id="arrow"></div>
            </td>


    <form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="process" value="add_report">
        <td>
            <div id="conditionals">
                <?include('ajax/condition.php');?>
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>
            <div id="orderby">
                <?include('ajax/order.php');?>
            </div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>
            <input type="submit" name="genSQL" value="getSQL()" id="submitPersonData" style="float: right;">
        </td></tr>
    </form>
```

Both condition.php and order.php are dynamically loaded via Jquery and have form elements in them (such as text boxes, check boxes and select boxes etc).  However when I post the form, the ajax-loaded elements dont get posted with it, all I get is the 'process' element and the submit button.

Any ideas why, and how to fix it please?

For more info:

EDIT:

When I extracted just the HTML from chrome's developer tools I ran the 'pre-generated' form as an HTM file, and it worked perfectly fine.  Its a jquery problem, and I don't know how to fix it.

**EDIT:**
I have found the solution to the problem.  The  and  Were outside of the form boundries (i.e. **not** in a cell box) which caused the form to be mis-interpreted.  Thank you for all your help and I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Both, the jQuery and your php could be helpful.

Comment: the jquery will not help you, it is simply $("#condtion").load(file)

Comment: and there is no PHP apart from posting the $_GET and $_POST vars at the end.

Comment: are you binding ajax before dom is loaded ?

Comment: @hardik no the two pages do not have any content when the DOM is loaded, only after the user selects some values in a SELECT table giving the two pages information to work with.

Comment: you still need to show us all the code involved if you want to get a precise answer.

Comment: @Musa HTML is not invalid, you are just seeing a part of it.  I close off the table and form.

Comment: @Chud37 it would be really helpful if you could post the generated form at jsfiddle

Comment: But it's loading lots of information from a database, I cant do that.

Comment: I have added lots more information.  Can anyone help???

Comment: Post the generated html, just the table containing the form. To do this use `view source` and copy the table

Comment: To provide an answer, we need to see the generated HTML. Censor it if it's sensitive data, but without it we can only guess - not answer

Comment: view source only gives me the blank data, i cant seem to see it dynamically generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was starting the form in between  and  statements, causing the form to be be displayed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You state that:

> Both condition.php and order.php are dynamically loaded via Jquery

But in your code, you have this:

```
<? include('ajax/condition.php'); ?>
```

Which is [including](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file on page load, **not** using AJAX.

Remove any attempts of jQuery dynamic loading. Instead, check your file path and file name of the `condition.php` and `order.php` files, that should reside inside of your `ajax/` folder. Please also make sure that the `ajax` folder exists in the root folder. Use `echo getcwd();` to print the current working directory.

Comment: They load because they will eventually have pre-existing data when the POST works correctly.  And like i said, the form is displaying fine through AJAX but I am not getting any output the other end.

Comment: The two files are loaded by jQuery when the user highlights a line in a multi-line multi-select <SELECT>.  They load fine using jQuery.  The form does not post fine.  I understand the need for trouble solving, but everyone is presuming I am not doing what I am saying I am doing.

Comment: If the include statements are not in your actual code, then please edit your question to represent the real code that you want help with. You negative, defending attitude is really undermining your credibility and your chances to get help, so cool off. Lean back and think about how to best explain your situation. Use FireBug or Chrome/Safari Dev Tools or IE's F12 to see the HTML that is loaded with AJAX and post it in your question. Help us to help you, and we don't get paid so try to be nice. And don't defend yourself, not in a comment below this either. I'm trying to help.

Comment: The files are loaded on page load with the includes, then with the jQuery when the user selects from a <SELECT> box. I am not trying to be negative or defensive and I apolagise if that is what is coming across.  What most likely is coming across is slight frustration at the fact that people seem to like to critisise code and not help with the initial question.  I am simply looking for reasons why It may not work.  I have posted alot of the code, but the actual page is very very long and I have posted the relevent part here.  I did not mean to offend anyone; especially anyone trying to help me.